# How do translate strings.xml to orientals languages?

Tags: android, xml, encoding, utf-8

I know it looks like a stupid question xD, but what I do not know is, if the `utf-8` encoding will alter or otherwise show the oriental languages (Russian, Chinese, Japanese, etc.) in those countries. 1. Could you tell me if the `<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>` must be taken into account when translating the strings? 2. And if so, then when you are going to translate into the Russian language for example, you should go to the `<? Xml version = "1.0" encoding = "koi8-r"?>` and so on with the other languages if you have your own coding?. 3. Also if you have an EditText should that be taken into account? This is because the app does a search to an api for a keyword. Please, help me because in the Spanish community nobody replied me :(.

PD: Translated by Google Translator :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 encoding is a "universal" encoding. It has codepoints for all the possible alphabets, even for emojis. So, if you use UTF-8 you don't need to use any other encoding.

Mind that you need to be sure it is being used everywhere (which is quite common nowadays): in your source code, resources, network calls, server code and database. Give that it looks like you're only using client side, you just need to make sure that UTF-8 is used everywhere in your source code. If you're using Android Studio you are covered. Check at the bottom of the window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating an api in android you can use Google Cloud translation Api. This api will do the translation for you, you can include this api in the one you are developing (it supports java, php, ruby, python programming languages) and it will translate to more than 100 different languages. Take a look to this link (Is in spanish since you aren't confortable wiht english language):

https://cloud.google.com/translate/?hl=es

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but, i'm not creating an API xD. i just want that my app be in too much languages, so, i'm translating word to word from strings.xml because sometimes Google Translator is not very accuracy with the context :/.

Comment: but bro... will u translate your app "manually"? xD! Wow maybe your childs will finish the job lol. Normally people use tools as the one I mentioned above or they offer a currency value (if it's a game) to normal user who are willing to help translating the code.

Comment: Jejeje yes xD, only 30 languages.